# Is it guaranteed that each Facebook user has an email returned via the login API?

Tags: android, facebook, email, authentication

By requesting the email permission, an app can access the user's primary email address. I want to provide users a way to login via the Facebook button as well as using email/password.

However, my app relies on the existence of an email address for each user. Is it guaranteed that all users that login via Facebook will have an email address?

Comment: no guaranteed to get email of all the user it may happen some user registered with mobile number.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK facebook will not guaranteed that your email address is returned. But we need to make sure it should have some email generated in a unique way. So I implemented by one way.

1. First check  wheather email id you got from FB by method  `String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();`
2. So if your email is empty then you are sure that graph user is returned. So by method `graphUser.getUsername()`you will get username which one is unique. So just append **`@facebook.com`** .

Again this solution is worked for me check with your requirements

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution!